# Can I have a windows service run a batch file to modify environment variables?

Tags: windows

I've created an application (*in C++ although I don't think that matters*) that runs as a windows service, the purpose of this service is to launch and manage other applications and script files.

Some of the script files that it must run need to create and modify environment variables which can be accessed by other scripts and applications.

If I create a .bat file with the content:

```
SETX /M fooVar 101010101
```

and run it from a cmd.exe window with administrator privileges then it works. However when I run it from my service using Createprocess as follows:

```
CreateProcess( LPTSTR(filePath.c_str()),      //path and application name
  LPTSTR(cmdArgs.c_str()),                    // Command line
  NULL,                                       // Process handle not inheritable
  NULL,                                       // Thread handle not inheritable
  TRUE,                                       // Set handle inheritance
  NULL,                                       // Creation flags
  LPTSTR(envVars.c_str()),                    // Environment Variables 
  LPTSTR(launchDir.c_str()),                  // Starting Directory
  &si,                                        // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
  &pi )                                       // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
```

where:

`filepath` = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

`cmdArgs` = /c "C:\testFiles\foo.bat"

then standard output reads:

> C:>SETX /M fooVar 101010101
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

Yet the environment variable has not been changed.

*I'd like to avoid changing my application, ideally I'm looking for an alternative to the `setx /M` to use in bat scripts which will work from a windows service. Or a way to give my service additional permissions if that will allow `setx /M` to work.*

Comment: Environment variables are scoped to the user session I believe. Services run in their own session. It is changing the environment for its session and not globally for everything. What about storing a registry value or a value in a file that gets looked up.

Comment: @Mike The setx /M parameter's description reads "Specifies that the variable should be set in
the system wide (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
environment. The default is to set the
variable under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER
environment." So I was expecting it to work for the entire system. But yes certainly, if you know a command which will set a registry value I can make that work. I'll research that approach once I'm back at work, thanks.

Comment: *Update*: I figured out that the environment variables are being changed, but as Mike said it's only being changed for the windows service. This is actually good behavior for my use-case. However the service is not restarted when the env var changes so it doesn't pick-up the new value. This is a problem and I'll post the solution that I come up with.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly anyways? Does it have to be a batch file? Powershell is much better.

Comment: @mike the company has a whole pile of existing programs and scripts. At present they're all run from a giant batch file of doom. My program is to replace the batch file with someone a little more intelligent that can handle schedules and what-not. I can't replace all of the scripts that already exist so I need to be able to run bat files, a long with lots of other script types. One thing that the old bat file did was set a local variable early on, and then pass it to several other scripts. Which is behavior I need to emulate.

Comment: I'll suggest you take a look at powershell. You can do pretty much anything you could do in .NET and call batch files. You could slowly start swapping out the old unwieldy stuff for more maintainable code. Powershell supports all the stuff one would be used to with a programming language like control flow (if, while, foreach, etc).